# How to parse object by string in Angular 4

Tags: angular, parsing

I need to parse an object by string key like it does AngualarJS $parse sevice.
I have an object

```
message = {
  text: 'msome text',
  userFrom: {
    name: 'Alex'
  }
}
```

And I have a string "userFrom.name"

How can I get message.userFrom.name value by using some Angular 4 service and "userFrom.name" string?

In AngularJS it can be done like this:

```
$parse("userFrom.name")(message) === 'Alex';
```

Comment: Can you add some more context to your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such service in the new Angular, but you can used any standard JS lib to do it.

Like [object-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path) on NPM

Install the lib with `npm install --save object-path`

Install the Typescript typings with `npm install --save-dev @types/object-path`

Then in your code

```
import * as objectPath from 'object-path'

const message = {
  text: 'msome text',
  userFrom: {
    name: 'Alex'
  }
}

objectPath.get(message, "userFrom.name") === 'Alex'
```

Comment: Okay. This will work. The same function I can create on my own, but I wanted to know how the Angular 4 does it.

Comment: I don't think Angular offer this kind of service in its public API anymore. HTML templates are compiled using JIT or AOT compilation. When browsing Angular source code, you can find classes about template parsing in https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface with the properties as in the object as below,

```
export interface IMessage{
  text:string;
  userFrom:{
    name:string;
  }
}
```

Then you can parse the object as

```
(<IMessage>this.message).userFrom.name; // gives Alex
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/owkxhGNjLJr0aOZrvJfI?p=preview)

Comment: @salik want to use a string value to target the object attribute. The path `'userFrom.name'` can be stored in some variable, and then used in the object

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Aravind in Angular 4 there is no such service, like $parse in AngularJS so I wanted to know how Angular 4 does. How it parses bindings like {{item.param1.param2}}. AngularJS uses $parse service. What the Angular 4 uses? And how can I use the same things?

Comment: did you see the above demo link?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) you can import `getterForProp`

```
import { getterForProp } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/utils";
```

then you can create a function like this:

```
tryToGetValue(obj: any, propName: string) {

    if (!obj || !propName) {
        return null;
    }

    let valueGetter = getterForProp(propName);
    let parsedValue = valueGetter(obj, propName);

    if (!parsedValue) {
        return null;
    }
    return parsedValue;
}
```

you can find the implementation in [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/033f410e7e057356a89cd156cf5894fc7978ab26/src/utils/column-prop-getters.ts) or just copy the functions in your project and call the `getterForProp`. `getterForProp` is returning one of three function base on the string that you pass to the function. then you need to invoke that function and pass the object and the string again. it will do the job for you.